# Popper isn't getting a z-index?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the following component:

https://material-ui.com/components/popper/

In the DOM, it has the role of tooltip. I expect that it would automatically get the tooltip zIndex from the theme here:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/zIndex.js

But it gets no z-index. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're using a component that is too low-level. The `zIndex.tooltip` you've mentioned is being used in the [`Tooltip`](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/) component. So you have two options:

1. Switch your code to be using `Tooltip` directly and don't worry about applying zIndexes around
2. Keep your `Popper` implementation apply the zIndex manually. Or use `withStyles`, just like the [`Tooltip` component does](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/2b980645da9789854a36120c3bf1dfc5be9199aa/packages/material-ui/src/Tooltip/Tooltip.js#L18).

For a greater flexibility and control over how stuff gets done, I would prefer the second approach, to be fair.